# Joomla 2.5 retrieve new registered ID of user

Tags: function, joomla

Someone may be able to help me to know how to retrieve the new id of a registered user.

I am needing it inside the **components/com_users/controllers/registration.php** file though.

This is because I have set an auto login after registration script in there and I am doing a little database insert but I need the users id to insert as well.

I know in joomla 1.5.2x i could use this

```
$newuid = $user->get('id');
```

But in 2.5 that doesn't seem to exist in the function for register() Starting on line 97 
on this file **components/com_users/controllers/registration.php**

So if anyone knows how I can collect the newly registered id that would be great :)

Cheers
John

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT id FROM #__users WHERE username = ' . $db->quote($data['username']));
$id = $db->loadResult();
```

However, I wouldn't recommend editing the "Joomla Core". The Joomla-way would probably be to create a plugin that gets a callback on the [onAfterStoreUser](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onAfterStoreUser).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(); 
$newuserid = $user->id;
```

I haven't tested it on 2.5 but think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In joomla 2.5 you can get it by

```
JFactory::getUser()->id;
```

It will return 0 if you are not log in.